# React :Cannot read proprieties on null (useContext) error whenever I use "useParams"

Tags: reactjs

I searched a solution for this on many websites and subreddits but I could not find the answer to this issue, I have been learning React on YT but there was a function that kept giving me errors (`useParams`), so I tried to use the specific code the person used in the video and it still didn't work. It kept giving me this error:

```
Cannot read proprieties on null (useContext)
```

So what should have happened was a text (h2) displaying the current param of the URL. I will attach the following code below:

**the App.js file**

```
import Navbar from './Navbar';

import Home from './Home';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Create from './Create';

import BlogDetails from './BlogDetails';

function App() {

return (

<Router>

<div className="App">

<Navbar />

<div className="content">

<Switch>

<Route exact path="/">

<Home />

</Route>

<Route path="/create">

<Create />

</Route>

<Route path="/blogs/:id">

<BlogDetails />

</Route>

</Switch>

</div>

</div>

</Router>

);

}

export default App;
```

**the BlogDetails file**

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const BlogDetails = () => {

const { id } = useParams();

return (

<div className="blog-details">

<h2>Blog details - { id }</h2>

</div>

);

}

export default BlogDetails;
```

Comment: It means `id` is null try to console log it

Comment: For some reason nothing pops up, it just logs the same error, I can show u the errors if want